# MVC design pattern and timers

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, timer, pyqt, qtimer

I am tring to understand MVC design pattern but using timers in the design is a little bit confusing.

I have an application that show the webcam on a gui.
The model contains the webcam logic (initialize, get_frame ecc) The view contains the widgets (I am using PyQt but the framework is not the problem here) that show the image.

I am using a timer (Qt timer) to call `update_frame` every 1/30 s. `update_frame` calls `model.get_frame` to get the new image.

Should the timer belonging to the view ? 
What if `get_frame` waits the image to be ready ( like a blocking function ) and I want to update the image as soon as a new image is ready ?
Where do I put the infinite loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The timer is the controller since it modifies the model.  So the timer shouldn't go in the view.  Add some code for more help.